# Equivalence of Norms and Open Mapping Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space with two norms $||\quad||_{1}$, $||\quad||_{2}$, making $V$ a complete normed vector space. Assume $\exists C$ (constant) such that:

$||v||_{2} \leq C||v||_{1}, \forall v \in V$

Hence, it follows that both norms are equivalent.

---

I was told to use the Open Mapping Theorem in this case, but I'm not sure on how to apply it. How would be a way to prove this result? I was thinking of using as an appropriate mapping $\mathrm{Id}: V \rightarrow V$ (the identity mapping) which will allow us to use the Open Mapping Thoerem, however I don't know how to proceed after this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Consider the identity operator $I:(V,\|.\|_1)\to(V,\|.\|_2)$.  By hypothesis this is a bounded linear operator which is a bijection and hence by open mapping theorem its inverse will again be bounded, i.e., $I:(V,\|.\|_2)\to(V,\|.\|_1)$ is bounded, which proves that the two norms are equivalent

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't really see why would this help. I think I'm missing something fundamental. What would be the concrete definition for a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ to be bounded, where $(X,d_1)$ and $(Y,d_2)$ are metric spaces? As well, wasn't the open mapping theorem stating that if $O \subset V$ is open, then $f(O)$ is open in $V$ (say the above conditions hold for $f: V \rightarrow V$)? Why would the boundedness of the inverse follow? Sorry for the questions.

Comment: See you are working in normed spaces and you might know that a linear operator is continuous if and only if it is bounded. Also note that if $f$ is a bijection and an open map then $f^{-1}$ is continuous. Now combine these and the result will follow.....I would also like to mention that a bounded function between metric spaces is different from a bounded linear operator between normed spaces as the definition might tell you....In fact a linear operator is bounded if and only if it takes bounded sets to bounded sets which might not be the case with bounded functions between metric spaces.

Comment: Finally got it, completely missed the point. Thanks!